# Notion of « piece of continuously differentiable manifold » in Lichnerowicz book

Tags: derivatives, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I am reading Linear algebra and analysis by André Lichnerowicz and there is a notion on which I find nothing on the internet.

First the context : We consider $E$ and $F$ real Euclidean spaces of dimension m and n ($m\leq n$).We denote by $E_{z}$ the space of vectors with origin $z\in E$ that is the vector space

$$
\{ y\in E : y = x - z, x\in E\}
$$

The differential of a function $f$ at a point x is noted $L(x,dx)$.

Now for a differentiable function $f$ and a fixed $x$ we assign to every vector $dx\in E_{x}$ the corresponding vector $dy = L(x,dx)$ of $F_{y}$ and we represent by $G_y$ the set of vectors $dy$ thus obtained.

We consider functions $f$ from a domain $\Delta\subset E$ to $\Delta_1\subset F$ that are differentiable and satisfy the followings conditions :

- $f$ is bijective
- For all $x\in \Delta$, the differential $L(x,dx)$ from $E_{x}$ onto $G_{y}$ is bijective

We call these functions the functions of class $H_1$.

Now the definition of a piece of a continuously differentiable manifold. Here the domain $\Delta$ is an m dimensional block of the space $E$.

> The domain $\Delta_1$ which is the image of the $m-block$ $\Delta$ under a function of class $H_1$ is called a piece of a continuously differentiable manifold of dimension $m$ embedded in F.

In order to have a better understanding of this notion I tried to see other sources on the internet but I cannot find this notion elsewhere. Have you ever heard about this notion of piece of continuously differentiable manifold ?

Thank you !

Comment: This is a very unusual terminology (and also very unusual notation $dx$ for vectors). Is there a reason you are using this book to learn differentiable manifolds?

Comment: @MoisheKohan Not really except that the book first start with a treatment of linear, tensor and exterior algebra which was my initial interest. Then it follows with  this chapter on differentiable manifold. It seems,  by looking more carefully to the book and other introduction to differentiable manifold, that the author try to avoid any topological consideration

Comment: I think you should change the book, there are many options.